# How can I extract an object from array?

Tags: javascript

I need to remove some object from an array of object ('types') and create another array called 'newtypes'

```
let types = [
  {value:"a", label:"xxx", component: "Demographic"},
  {value:"b", label:"xxx", component: "Elastic"}, 
  {value:"c", label:"xxx", component: "Another"}, 
  {value:"d", label:"xxx", component: "Another2"}, 
];

let props = [{user : {new_functions_id: [
  {component: "Demographic", function_count: 4, new_functions_id: 2}, 
  {component: "Elastic", function_count: 2, new_functions_id: 1}, 
]}}
];
console.log(types);
console.log(props);

/*
I have to create this var:

let newtypes = [
  {value:"a", label:"xxx", component: "Demographic"},
  {value:"b", label:"xxx", component: "Elastic"}, 
];

*/
```

I'm trying to loop the array with:

```
newtypes = types.map( a => {
        if(a.component == b.component)

});
```

But I'm stucked thinking how to compare or check if the values of the 2nd array are in the first one.

Comment: Seems like filter() would be a good choice.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: Use reduce function.

Comment: Is the format of the `props` object consistent? Will it always be `props[0].user.new_functions_id` to access the array with the components? Or will there be multiple props, all with `user.new_functions_id`, and you need to include *all* of them?

Comment: `let newtypes` as I put in the end of the question. The same first var but without the elements present in `props`

Comment: ^ You just need to remove the negation `!` from the duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine `filter` and `find` to get only the items with matching component:

```js
let types = [
  {value:"a", label:"xxx", component: "Demographic"},
  {value:"b", label:"xxx", component: "Elastic"},
  {value:"c", label:"xxx", component: "Another"},
  {value:"d", label:"xxx", component: "Another2"},
];

let props = [{user : {new_functions_id: [
   {component: "Demographic", function_count: 4, new_functions_id: 2},
   {component: "Elastic", function_count: 2, new_functions_id: 1},
 ]}}
];

const newTypes = types.filter(type => 
  props[0].user.new_functions_id.find(id => id.component === type.component)
)

console.log(newTypes)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the item from the first array is in the second array you can try the following: types.filter(a => b.includes(a))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
first map() and then filer().